# How do you Sort a DataTable given column and direction?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I need to resort, in memory, a DataTable based on a column and direction that are coming from a GridView. The function needs to look like this:

```
public static DataTable resort(DataTable dt, string colName, string direction)
{
    DataTable dtOut = null;

    ....
}
```

I need help filling in this function. I think I can use a Select statement but I am not sure how. I can't click on Comments because of this browser but you can show me an in-place or new DataTable solution, either one. For the people showing me pointers, please, I need a coded function similar to the one prototyped.

How about:

```
// ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort="au_fname DESC";
   public static void Resort(ref DataTable dt, string colName, string direction)
   {
        string sortExpression = string.Format("{0} {1}", colName, direction);
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression;
   }
```

Answer (score 119):

I assume "direction" is "ASC" or "DESC" and dt contains a column named "colName"

```
public static DataTable resort(DataTable dt, string colName, string direction)
{
    DataTable dtOut = null;
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = colName + " " + direction;
    dtOut = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    return dtOut;
}
```

OR without creating dtOut

```
public static DataTable resort(DataTable dt, string colName, string direction)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = colName + " " + direction;
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work the first time but not subsequent times. When I set my defaultView.Sort a second time to a different column direction, the table in the gridView diappears....

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's overwriting the tableStyles.GridCOlumnStyles

Comment: You can also simplify the second code block to simply return `dt.DefaultView.ToTable();`.

Answer (score 74):

If you've only got one DataView, you can sort using that instead:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "columnName asc";
```

Haven't tried it, but I guess you can do this with any number of DataViews, as long as you reference the right one.

Comment: great! this solution works and is 10x easier than all of these custom sort methods

Comment: Not sure why the other solution has more upvotes but this is the one you are after if you came to this thread. Thanks Alex. It works.

Answer (score 21):

Actually got the same problem. For me worked this easy way:

Adding the data to a `Datatable` and sort it:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "columnname";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 7):

DataTables have an overloaded Select method that you can you to do this. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx

But the return val of the Select call is not a DataTable but an array of RowData objects. If you want to return a DataTable from your function you will have to build it from scratch based on that data array. Here is a post that addresses and provides a sample for both issues: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/157a4a0f-1324-4301-9725-3def95de2bf2/

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to sort in more than one direction

```
  public static void sortOutputTable(ref DataTable output)
        {
            DataView dv = output.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = "specialCode ASC, otherCode DESC";
            DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
            output = sortedDT;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a **DataView**. You cannot sort a DataTable directly, but you can create a DataView from the DataTable and sort that.

Creating: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc.aspx

Sorting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13wb36xf.aspx

> The following code example creates a view that shows all the products
>   where the number of units in stock is less than or equal to the
>   reorder level, sorted first by supplier ID and then by product name.

`DataView prodView = new DataView(prodDS.Tables["Products"],
   "UnitsInStock <= ReorderLevel",
   "SupplierID, ProductName",
   DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);`