# Sorting on Column of datatable as alphabetically..or filter column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to sort all the data of `DataTable`, I want sort on `Column2` as alphabetically.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(DT);
dv.Sort = "Column2 ASC";
DT.DefaultView.Sort = "Column2 ASC";
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: i used this code but it not work correct or not proper output @AmitSingh

Comment: this question was already answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005658/how-do-you-sort-a-datatable-given-column-and-direction)

Comment: Looks like you just need to assing `DT.DefaultView` to `dv`. Like, `DataView dv = DT.DefaultView;`

Comment: What are you using as datasource for the webdatabound control, the view or the table?

Comment: i bound the data in dataset from XML file i just read Xml Doc file and store in dataset @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Micheljeams: I think you have misunderstood me, if you use the `DataTable` as datasource and you sort the `DataView`, the table itself remains unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataView dv = yourDataTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "Column2";                
yourDataTable = dv.ToTable();
```

You don't need to add ASC, it's a default, unless you want DESC :) This code worked for me :)

Comment: but i want sort on first character of Column string type ..so is it Possible..! @gintas k

Comment: The above code sorts all the datarows in datatable ascending (A-Z) by the values in the column named "Column2". What are you trying to do exactly? @Micheljeams :)