# Sort DataTable based on date column(dd MMM yyyy)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset ds and i need to sort the datatabel of the same ds based on a column and the column name is Date. The values on this column is in 'dd MMM yyyy' format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14031086/1134076 < This what you are looking for

Comment: It's not a question, it's request. No code, no effort just specification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you Sort a DataTable given column and direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005658/how-do-you-sort-a-datatable-given-column-and-direction)

Comment: what is the type of coloumn ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the column type to Date then try Linq solution as below

```
var recs = dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(x =>DateTime.ParseExact(
             x.Field<string>("Date"),
                           "dd MMM yyyy", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: You have a typo in there should be dd MM yyyy and DateTime.ParseExact() :) good answer

Comment: @Onam sorry, i did't get you

Comment: Look at the format of the date you are converting it to dd MMM yyyy. Note the 3 characters to represent a month. Also DateTime.ParaseExact is misspelled and just noticed CultureInfo.InvariantCultur needs to be CultureInfo.InvariantCulture (note the 'e' at the end). Other than that perfect :)

Comment: @Onam - OP has `MMM`, not `MM`. @Damith - You wrote `ParaseExact` instead of `ParseExact`.

Comment: @Onam and Corak, Thanks both of you.

Answer (score -1):

That's going to be a problem particularly if it's a large table. The best answer of course, would be to redefine the column as a date type. That way it'll sort and join efficiently. If the table is not large, though, you can reformat the date string to ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD), and it will sort correctly.  You didn't mention which database you using, and the string and date functions vary among platforms: here's a SQL Server example:

```
 SELECT CAST([Date] AS Date) AS real_date,
        my_other_fields
   FROM MyTable
```

I'm at home, so I don't have a SQL Server to test this on right now (I can update the example in the morning if it doesn't work), but that date format is pretty unambiguous to parse, so I expect that the cast will work okay.

If you want to take care of this entirely on the application side, it should be fairly straightforward to write a string function will reorder the year, month and day in the date string.

Comment: In fact i am using sql server 2008.

Comment: @AnuBasheerA   I've added a snippet to my answer:  I'm pretty sure it will work as written, but will confirm as soon as I come back to the office.

Comment: @AnuBasheerA And, having checked, the cast works just fine (as long as the string is well-formed).