# Order by Year and Month in Datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to sort the data present in the DataTable by Year in descending order and month in ascending order. But it is not sorting data as expected.

Code used for this as as below

```
DataTable sortedtTable = currentBalanceData.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year).ThenBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month).CopyToDataTable();
```

and output of the same is below

[image]

Let me know what I am doing wrong. Expected output is as below

2017 01

2017 02

2017 03

2017 04

2017 05

2017 06

2017 07

2017 08

2016 01

2016 02

2016 03

2016 04

2016 05

2016 06
..... and so on.

**Edit --> Sorting working only for year.**

```
 DataTable sortedtTable1 = currentBalanceData.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year).ThenBy(y => y.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month).CopyToDataTable();
```

output of the sortedtTable1  is as below

[image]

Comment: I dont have an answer... but you are using OrderByDescending and then ThenBy, idk for sure but to me that reads that it would keep the sort direction from the previous call. So call the descending sort, and then the ThenBy would still use a descending direction. I wonder if you need to do it in two separate lines rather than chaining them together. This is ugly but maybe you sort by year and break out each separate year into another list then sort by month, then combine the lists into the master list after those are done. If you dont care about speed or memory give it a try.

Comment: @KyleRone thanks for the response. As per the details given in below URL we can use ThenBy with the combination of the OrderBy. I followed the same to achieve my expected sorting. https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/linq-thenby-and-thenbydescending/

Comment: Either no repro or I missed something ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/iwQr1k

Comment: Code looks OK. So, here is my shot in the dark. Just verify what does **Field<DateTime>("date").Month** is returning. I hope it's not "1" always because it might be resolving by "mm/dd/yyyy" format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5005717/34092

Comment: I wish people start binding datagridview to any IEnumerable<T. Anything in System.Collections , will give better type contrôle, searching, and ordering. And no DB null.
And a POCO is way easier that adding column.  DataView is cool but it's prone to Typos.

Comment: @mjwills I am able to view the sorted datatable by applying order by (ascending) on year. Order by is not working only for Month.

Comment: Show us the attempt please, so I can compare it to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/sorting-and-filtering-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN .

Comment: ops it has broken all images updating once again

Comment: @mjwills done please check

Comment: Resolved. It was not working because of the date format. I assumed it is mm/dd/yyyy but actually it is mm/dd/yyyy. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Can't believe I was right!! Hilarious :)

Answer (score -1):

You might be ordering by something else this datasource, or overwriting it.
Because it Works as you expect it. Like shown in this [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UnDdwM)

```
var years = Enumerable.Range(2015,2);
var months = Enumerable.Range(1,5);

var dates =     (from y in years
                from m in months
                select new DateTime(y,m,1) // public DateTime (int year, int month, int day);
                 ).ToList();



var ordered = dates.OrderByDescending(d=> d.Year).ThenBy(d=> d.Month);      
ordered.Select(x=> $"{x.Year}/{x.Month}").Dump();
/*
Dumping object(System.Linq.SelectIPartitionIterator`2[DateTime,String])
[
   2016/1          ,
   2016/2          ,
   2016/3          ,
   2016/4          ,
   2016/5          ,
   
   2015/1          ,
   2015/2          ,
   2015/3          ,
   2015/4          ,
   2015/5
]
*/
```

This match your expected result.

And `OrderByDescending`, `ThenByDescending`. matches the grid picture

```
var ordered2 = dates.OrderByDescending(d=> d.Year).ThenByDescending(d=> d.Month);   
ordered2.Select(x=> $"{x.Year}/{x.Month}").Dump();
/*
Dumping object(System.Linq.SelectIPartitionIterator`2[DateTime,String])
[
   2016/5          ,
   2016/4          ,
   2016/3          ,
   2016/2          ,
   2016/1          ,
   
   2015/5          ,
   2015/4          ,

   2015/3          ,
   2015/2          ,
   2015/1
]
*/
```

This behavior is consitent even on a DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(dates, "Date")) {
    table.Load(reader);
}

var orderedWithDT = table.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year).ThenBy(y => y.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month);       
orderedWithDT.SelectMany(x=> x.ItemArray).Dump();
```

> 01/01/2016   ,
> 02/01/2016   ,
> 03/01/2016   ,
> 04/01/2016   ,
> 05/01/2016   ,
> 01/01/2015   ,
> 02/01/2015   ,
> 03/01/2015   ,
> 04/01/2015   ,
> 05/01/2015